# Why is File locked for exclusive use for me but not another person?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint Enterprise 2010 we are having some issues where a user (lets call user A) goes in and opens an excel file (does not Check-In) and closes the file.  I (user B) then try to open the file and it says file is locked for exclusive use by user A and the file opens as read only. In fact the library for me shows a light red rectangle with the verbiage **File is locked for exclusive use**

I then ask user C to go to the library and open. User C does not see a red rectangle with warning and has no issues opening and saving the file. I go into the file to try again and I see the same red warning rectangle and when I open the file it only allows me to open it as read only, but gives me the option to be notified when available.

Why is this occurring. I have switched the default to open on client rather than server to see if this helps. Eventually I am able to edit/save the file but typically after 30 minutes or so.

Comment: i think file is checked out by user A.just tell him to check it in or make undo check out and it should work for you

Comment: Its not checked out as the user has no clue how to check out a document...What do you mean..."make undo checkout"